# How to build a winium Driver service on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, selenium, automation, ui-automation, desktop

I am using the following class code for launching calculator via WiniumDriver. Before creating an instance of WiniumDriver, I am starting a winium driver service.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.DesktopOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriverService;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {

    static WiniumDriver driver = null;
    static WiniumDriverService service = null;
    static DesktopOptions options = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupEnvironment(){
        options = new DesktopOptions(); //Instantiate Winium Desktop Options
        options.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
        File driverPath = new File("C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.winium.desktop.driver","C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
        service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true)
                .withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
        try {
            service.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while starting WINIUM service");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void startDriver(){
        driver = new WiniumDriver(service,options);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void stopDriver(){
        driver.close();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
        service.stop();
    }
```

After running the test class as TestNG item, following exception is observed.

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest startDriver
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver.<init>(WiniumDriver.java:75)
    at com.bravura.automation.CalculatorTest.startDriver(CalculatorTest.java:41)
```

I double checked the path to calc.exe and Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe, still I am not able to launch the WiniumDriverService. Is there any other way to start this service? Does winium support windows 10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that, `'startDriver'` is executing before `setupEnvironment` method and the variables `service` and `options` are not initialized. Hence it is throwing null pointer exception.

because the order of execution in `testNG` is given below.

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeTest
@BeforeClass
@BeforeMethod
@Test
@AfterMethod
@AfterClass
@AfterTest
@AfterSuite
```

There are three solutions.

1. change the annotation for the following methods as given below. so that, the start driver will run after the setup environment method.

   ```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void startDriver(){
       driver = new WiniumDriver(service,options);
    }

   @AfterMethod
   public void stopDriver(){
      driver.close();
   }
   ```
2. change the annotations as given below.

   ```
   @BeforeTest
   public static void setupEnvironment(){
       options = new DesktopOptions(); //Instantiate Winium Desktop Options
       options.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
       File driverPath = new File("C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.winium.desktop.driver","C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
       service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true)
               .withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
       try {
           service.start();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Exception while starting WINIUM service");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @BeforeClass
   public void startDriver(){
       driver = new WiniumDriver(service,options);
   }

   @AfterClass
   public void stopDriver(){
       driver.close();
   }

   @AfterTest
   public void tearDown(){
       service.stop();
   }
   ```
3. change the annotations as given below. I believe, this one will be optimal solution.

   ```
   @BeforeTest
   public static void setupEnvironment(){
       options = new DesktopOptions(); //Instantiate Winium Desktop Options
       options.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
       File driverPath = new File("C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.winium.desktop.driver","C:\\Winium\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
       service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true)
               .withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
       try {
           service.start();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Exception while starting WINIUM service");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @BeforeMethod
   public void startDriver(){
       driver = new WiniumDriver(service,options);
   }

   @AfterMethod
   public void stopDriver(){
       driver.close();
   }

   @AfterTest
   public void tearDown(){
       service.stop();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Here is the correct way of using it

```html
public class SimpleTest
{
    DesktopOptions options;
    WiniumDriverService service;
    WiniumDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void bt()
    {
        //Instantiate Winium Desktop Options
        options = new DesktopOptions();
        
        // Path of application you want to run and test
        options.setApplicationPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
        
        //Path for Winium Desktop Driver
        File driverPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"drivers"+File.separator+"Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
        
        //Port is 9999, you can change it
        service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverPath).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
        
        try
        {
             service.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception while starting WINIUM service");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver = new WiniumDriver(service,options);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void at()
    {
        service.stop();
    }
}
```

2. If you need other configuration you can refer [this link](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/start-winium-server-automatically-and-launch-application). However, I would not recommend that you use Winium for Windows automation even for basic Calculator program it will not work properly, last release of Winium was in 2016, I don't think it is regularly maintained now. Instead use WinAppDriver, which is far better tool and with good documentation. To start with refer [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver)