# Getting Connection Refused Exception in the time of initializing Winium Driver

Tags: java, windows, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am new to winium technology, i tried to start my winium demo test i am getting exception like `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:`so can anyone please help me to solve this error.

My demo code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 String ApplicationPath="C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
 DesktopOptions options=new DesktopOptions();
 options.setApplicationPath(ApplicationPath);
 System.setProperty("webdriver.winium.driver.desktop", "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Downloads\\Winium.Desktop.Driver\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
 WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"),options);
```

}

///LogCat///

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9999 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-S3RV3MH', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: WiniumDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.execute(WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver.<init>(WiniumDriver.java:84)
    at winium.demo.WiniumDemo1.main(WiniumDemo1.java:23)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9999 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.execute(WiniumDriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Pretty obviously, nothing is listening on localhost:9999 or a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @Dave, so can you please help me to resolve this..i didnt have any idea on this networking and firewall things. it will great if you help me

Comment: You're telling the Selenium Driver to connect to something on localhost, port 9999. What do you expect Selenium to connect to?
For example, if you were to change "http://localhost:9999" to "http://stackoverflow.com" then your exception would disappear - but you'd likely have other problems, because you likely don't want to be telling Selenium to look at the StackOverflow website.

Comment: I agree with you dave.. but as per winium it starts on localhost:9999.. so i mentioned like that... can i change that local host with 127.0.0.1 something

Comment: The Winium Driver starts on port 9999, I haven't used Winium, but I presume it's similar to the Chromium driver. However, you have not demonstrated in your question here that you have actually started the WiniumDriver (and your posted code on this question doesn't start the WiniumDriver. I suggest you do more reading on Winium/Selenium, but as a starter, see point 3 in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165039/how-to-build-a-winium-driver-service-on-windows-10